# Import Sunrise/Set based on coordinates into Google Sheet using API

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've spent about 5 hours trying to figure this out and am getting stuck on the last bit.

So far, I have been able to call the https://sunrise-sunset.org/api to return all the data I need. The issue I'm running into is being able to parse the result so that it appends the sunrise or sunset value to a variable that I can export as a result in the google sheet.

Ideally, in the google sheet, I'd be able to use the custom function like any other like this

```
A1=SunRiseSet(lat,long,date,type)
```

="5:11:12 PM"

I'd like to use type to specify what value the function should return (sunrise or sunset).

Here is the code I have so far

```
function SunRiseSet(lat,long,date,type) {
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat="+lat+"&lng="+long+"&date="+date);  
  var json = response.getContentText();
  Logger.log(json);

  var data = JSON.stringify(json);
  Logger.log(data);
  var data = json;

  var sunrise = data.sunrise;

  var sunset = data.results.sunset

 type=1; 
  if(type==1){
   return this.sunrise}
  else{
   return this.sunset};
}
```

I'm sure this is really easy, but so far everything I've tried has failed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the following modifications?

### Modification points :

- The value of `sunrise` is at `data.results.sunrise`.
- `data.results.sunrise` and `data.results.sunset` can be retrieved by parsing using `JSON.parse()`.

The modified script which reflected above is as follows.

### Modified script :

```
function SunRiseSet(lat,long,date,type) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat="+lat+"&lng="+long+"&date="+date);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  var sunrise = data.results.sunrise;
  var sunset = data.results.sunset;
  if (type == 1) {
    return sunrise;
  } else {
    return sunset;
  };
}
```

### Usage :

- Please put `=SunRiseSet(lat,long,date,type)` to a cell on Spreadsheet.

For example,

- When you want `sunrise`.

  - Please put `=SunRiseSet(36.7201600,-4.4203400,"2017-12-31",1)` to a cell on Spreadsheet. Please enclose `date` by double quotes.
- When you want `sunset`.

  - Please put `=SunRiseSet(36.7201600,-4.4203400,"2017-12-31")` to a cell on Spreadsheet. You can use except for `1` to `type`. Also you can use without `type` like the sample.

These parameters are from [Sunset and sunrise times API](https://sunrise-sunset.org/api).

### References :

- [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)
- [Sunset and sunrise times API](https://sunrise-sunset.org/api)

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify.

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you! It was my first time working with JavaScript and I was a little confused whether or not I needed to use the JSON.parse or JSON.stringify to get this done. It's good to see I was at least close! -- to get it to work properly in the sheet, I had to convert the date to text that I could reference in the formula. Now my trip planning sheet automatically displays the sunset/rise for a given coordinate! Thank you!

Comment: The next step for me now will be to convert the UTC to local time based on the coordinates.

Comment: @Jeremy Bauman I'm glad your problem was solved. About your next problem, I'm sorry I couldn't understand it. Can you show us the detail? Or if you will post it as a new question including the detail information, I and other users will be able to also think of it.

Comment: I provided more detail below. Thank you so much for your help! I seem to be getting stuck pulling data from the JSON like I did before. I can't seem to figure out how to deal with the brackets. ex: "dates":[{..."sunrise":"2018-08-01 06:02"...

Comment: @Jeremy Bauman I'm sorry for confusing you. I confirmed your new question. Can you post that as a new question? Your added post to this question becomes an answer to your first question. So when you will post new question, please click top right "Ask Question" and post it. By this, other users can post each answer.

Comment: thank you for the clarification! I didn't mean to misuse the system, I have now posted the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48121362/google-sheets-custom-function-api-return-sunrise-sunset-gmt-dst-offset-based.

Comment: @Jeremy Bauman Thank you for posting it. I will check it. Also other users will be able to see it and answer to it.