# Google Sheets Custom Function API: Return Sunrise/sunset + GMT/DST Offset based on lat/long

Tags: json, api, google-apps-script, google-sheets, timezone

I'd like to have the function return the sunrise or sunset formatted with the appropriate GMT offset based on the coordinates. I found a different API that lets you get sunrise/set times for a given date and location as well as providing GMT or DST offset.

```
function SunRiseSet(lat,long,date,type) {
 var response  
 UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://api.geonames.org/timezoneJSON?"+lat+"&lng="+long+"&username=northfacejmb"+lat+"&lng="+long+"&date="+date);

 var json = response.getContentText();
 var data = JSON.parse(json);
 var sunrise = data.dates.sunrise;
 var sunset = data.dates.sunset;
 var gmtOffset = data.gmtOffset;
 var dstOffset = data.dstOffset;

 if (type == 1) {
    return sunrise-gmtOffset;
                 } else {
      return sunset-gmtOffset;
           };
}
```

Any help is appreciated! - Jeremy

For context: [Import Sunrise/Set based on coordinates into Google Sheet using API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48040528/import-sunrise-set-based-on-coordinates-into-google-sheet-using-api)

Comment: @NanceySchorr In this case google-apps-script should be used instead of google-spreadsheet-api.

Comment: @tanaike, thanks for the help. Looks like the issue I was having was with my JSON query. The code below solved the problem and it works perfectly. What is the purpose of the [0] in "data.dates[0].sunrise;"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using most of the code above, I was able to get it to work. had to include the [0] in the Json query. Also, the calculated sunrise/set with DST offset is already ready so no conversions are necessary.

```
function SunRiseSet(lat,long,date,type) {
  var url = "http://api.geonames.org/timezoneJSON?lat="+lat+"&lng="+long+"&username=northfacejmb&date="+date;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  var sunrise = data.dates[0].sunrise;
  var sunset = data.dates[0].sunset;
  var gmtOffset = data.gmtOffset;
  var dstOffset = data.dstOffset;
  if (type == 1) {
     return sunrise;
    } else {
     return sunset;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following modifications?

### Modification points :

- From "GeoNames Web Services Documentation", the endpoint you want is `http://api.geonames.org/timezone?lat=47.01&lng=10.2&username=demo&date=#####`. (This is a sample.)
- Data of `sunrise` and `sunset` is in the array of `dates`.
- In your script, `sunrise-gmtOffset` sums string and number. `sunrise` is not calculated as the time.

The modified script which is reflected above points is as follows.

### Modified script :

```
function SunRiseSet(lat,long,date,type) {
  var url = "http://api.geonames.org/timezoneJSON?lat="+lat+"&lng="+long+"&username=northfacejmb&date="+date;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  var sunrise = data.dates[0].sunrise;
  var sunset = data.dates[0].sunset;
  var gmtOffset = data.gmtOffset;
  var dstOffset = data.dstOffset;
  if (type == 1) {
    return conv(sunrise, gmtOffset);
  } else {
    return conv(sunset, gmtOffset);
  };
}

function conv(str, offset) {
  var r = str.replace(" ", "T");
  var converted = new Date(r);
  var d = new Date(converted.getTime() - offset * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  return Utilities.formatString("%s-%s-%s %s:%s:%s", d.getYear().toString(), addzero(d.getMonth()), addzero(d.getDate()), addzero(d.getHours()), addzero(d.getMinutes()), addzero(d.getSeconds()));
}

function addzero(num) {
  var str = num.toString();
  return str.length == 1 ? "0" + str : str;
}
```

### Note :

- `sunrise-gmtOffset` and `sunset-gmtOffset` for retrieving the result use your script. This modified script supposes these are the result you want.
- It seems that `sunrise` and `sunset` are always the format of `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm`. At `conv()`, this is used. If you want to use the regex, you can also use as follows.

  - `var r = str.match(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2})/); var converted = new Date(parseInt(r[1], 10), parseInt(r[2], 10), parseInt(r[3], 10), parseInt(r[4], 10), parseInt(r[5], 10));`

### References :

- [GeoNames Web Services Documentation](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks for helping, this seems to work mostly, but it is returning the GMT rather than the GMT offset. As is, it returns: Rise: 2018-00-09 14:24:00 
Set: 2018-00-09 23:57:00. For the given Lat/Long the correct values should be Rise: 2018-01-09 07:24:00 Set: 2018-01-09 16:57:00.

Comment: @Jeremy Bauman Thank you for your reply. I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I have 2 questions. 1. My answer depends on your initial question. Are ``sunrise-gmtOffset`` and ``sunset-gmtOffset`` in your question correct? 2. Can you provide the sample input and output values? ``For the given Lat/Long the correct values should be Rise: 2018-01-09 07:24:00 Set: 2018-01-09 16:57:00.`` What is the given Lat/Long and date? When the information is shared, it helps to do the debug.

Comment: I used the bulk of your code above but set it to return the sunrise/sunset. Looks like I was over complicating it when the API already outputs the correct time with DST offset. I don't know what I was thinking! Could you explain the purpose of the [0] in the JSON query?

Comment: @Jeremy Bauman Thank you for your additional information. I'm sorry I couldn't help you.